# Moblie view zoom / viewport issue

Tags: css, zooming, viewport

I would like to remove the zoom of my wordpress page when a mobile user visits. I would like to display the whole page zoomed out.

I get same result with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1">
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

How come?
Maybe there are som css that messes it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the viewport meta tag completely.  It is there to prevent the user from seeing the whole page zoomed out.

Comment: After som struggling i realized that i hade to delete in the child theme and parrent theme. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like the user to see the whole page zoomed out?

Maybe it was unclear in my description.

Comment: Yes, if you remove it, they will see the whole page zoomed out